# bm package with accent and subscript

Tags: accents, bm

I am trying to add bold subscript and superscript to a bold accented character. But the subscript comes out with a different spacing or depth from the version without the accent. I would like to just have a tilde above K in the first example.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
   \bm{K_{XX}}^{-1} \tilde{\bm K}^{-1}_{\bm{XX}} \bm{{\tilde{K}_{XX}}}^{-1} \bm{{\tilde{K}_{XX}^{-1}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. \bm{\tilde{K}_{XX}}^{-1} should be the solution. I was not able to use it because of a conflict between package accents and bm. The alternative is a nice way around it. A less elegant way would be \tilde{\bm{K}}_{\textit{\textbf{XX}}^{-1}, which looks close enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the last of these, I think:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
  K_{XX}^{-1}  \bm{K_{XX}}^{-1}    \bm{\tilde{K}_{XX}}^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to change to the modern toolchain, and compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[
   \symbfit{\tilde{K}_{XX}^{\symbfup{-1}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

If you use a math font that comes in bold, you can also load all your symbols from that bold font, with `\boldsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
\[
   \boldsymbol{\tilde{K}_{XX}^{-1}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Math Bold sample]

Comment: The second image is very strong bold :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano That’s Libertinus Math Bold. Minion Math comes in several different weights, which you can select with, e.g. `\setmathfont[version=bold]{Minion Math Semibold}`. No other OpenType math font does, and if there’s another I’m not aware of, please tell me about it!